# Why can't I target specific classes in a window click handler with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom-events

I just noticed that while this works to target `<a href="#" class="some-class">Click me</a>`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-class', event => { ... })
```

The following does not:

```
$(window).on('click', '.some-class', event => { ... })
```

However, this does register the click on the element:

```
$(window).on('click', event => { ... })
```

Why?

Comment: Your post is hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has less to do with events not bubbling up to `window` but jQuery's inability to select elements when the root element is `window`. `$(window).find(...)` will always return an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `window` is not part of the DOM, so events don't bubble up to it to be caught by your delegated event handler.

Comment: But the events do bubble up to `window`, don't they? I am confused as to why the non-class-specific handler registers the click.

Comment: No, they only bubble up as far as the document (assuming nothing stops them).

Comment: Again, how come `$(window).on('click', event => { ... })` picks up the event?

Comment: Vanilla JS does as well, e.g. `window.addEventListener('click', event => { console.log(event.target) })`

Comment: That's because you've attached the handler directly to the window. I'm not sure where the confusion lies. Do you have a specific issue you're attempting to address?

Comment: Well, the issue I have and just figured out was that my event handler was not called by using `$(window).on('click', '.some-class', event => { ... })`.

Comment: My confusion is also due to the fact that vanilla JS `window.addEventListener('click', event => { console.log(event.target) })` would print the correct DOM element that was clicked and I thought using jQuery with `$(window).on('click', '.some-class', event => { ... })` would simply be short for doing checks against the event.target inside the handler body.

Comment: Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/smares/pen/rNOBZRK?editors=1111